# Como Instalo MySQL en Manjaro existe un error en la pagina

Tags: mysql

Holaa, necesito instalar MySQL y la pagina me da un error, alguien sabe que esta pasando? que puedo hacer? [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esperar.. si la pagina te dice que no anda, que podemos hacer nosotros?